# Dell PERC H710P Raid Control reduced I/O speeds when idle

Tags: ssd, performance, hardware-raid, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PERC H710P Raid Controller card and 4 Dell Certified 600GB Solid State Drives configured in RAID-10. I have a Dell Poweredge R820. After performing benchmark tests using ATTO, I usually average 3.5Gb/s speeds for read and write.

The machine is still fairly new, and does not have anything running on it yet. I noticed however, when I leave the server on and unattended (no programs running, machine is idle), the next day I go and perform the benchmark test again using ATTO, the read and write speeds decrease to 1 Gb/s.

Read Policy = Adaptive Read Ahead,
Write Policy = Write Back,
Stripe Element Size = 64KB,
Disk Cache Policy = Enabled,

The only solution I have found to restore the read and write speeds back 3.5 Gb/s is to restart the server.... everyday...

Any thoughts on why the read and write speeds decrease when the machine sits idle for over a day or so?

Comment: Anyone able to chime in on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the power system profile in the BIOS and try setting it to 'Performance'. We've found a variety issues when the system is in power efficient mode. In addition to reduced storage i/o we've seen high latency on 10GbE networking and poor VM performance when the system is a hypervisor. But like your situation, the problems only manifest after the system has been running for a while.

Comment: Hello Will, Thank you for your suggestion. This post was from back in January and since then, we had Dell replace the whole machine through warranty and we have not had any issues with this new machine ever since... I'll go ahead and mark your answer as an accepted answer.